# Active Reports 3 new dll version binding redirects not working

Tags: .net, report

I recently made some upgrades to one of the Active Reports 3 (AR3) report DLLs that I use and I needed to use the 5.3.1436.2 (previously using 5.2.835.2).  Now, this is one report dll out of 30, and I didn't want to change the references for every report dll and test them.  I just did not have the time to do so.  So here is what I thought would work.

My dll has references to the 5.3 versions of the AR3 dlls.

The AR3 dlls are in the bin folder of the web application, along with my dll.

I then added the following, for each dll, to the web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentiy name="ActiveReports3"  publicKeyToken="cc4967777c49a3ff"  />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.2.835.2" newVersion="5.3.1436.2" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I checked before hand to make sure that the publicKeyTokens were the same for the 5.2 and 5.3 versions.  I also tried the example above and a [range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(vs.71).aspx) for the oldVersion, but neither work.

However, any report dll that doesn't directly reference the 5.3 dlls in its solution does not work.  There is always an error thrown about not being able to find one of the 5.2 versions of the dll or one of its dependents.

I've tried adding each version separately to the GAC, both at the same time and none at all.  No variation worked.  It was my understanding that this is the situation that binding redirects were meant for.

Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:  Managed to get fuslogvw working, here's the log:

```
LOG: Assembly Name is: ActiveReports.PdfExport, Version=5.3.1436.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Note, this is with the binding redirect in the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you nearly had it.

The assemblyIdentity you list above is for ActiveReports3.dll and the issue is with one of its subassemblies ActiveReports.PdfExport.  You'll need a bindingredirect for EVERY DLL that changed versions.  Painful, for sure, but at least there's an easy path to solving the problem... provided the publicKeyToken doesn't change.